# Is there an easy way with (T-)SQL to transform rows into columns like this?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

So let's say I have 3 tables like

```
       Questions 
========================
 id |     qtext 
========================
 1  | "What is 3 x 23?"
------------------------
 2  | "Your age?"

      Registrants
========================
 id |    name 
========================
 1  | "Jason" 
------------------------
 2  | "Subhasish"

               Answers
======================================
 registrant_id | question_id  | val 
======================================
      1        |       1      |  69
--------------------------------------
      2        |       2      |  45
--------------------------------------
      1        |       2      |  26
```

Is there a way to create from this a table like

```
                  AnswersByPartner
==================================================
     Name     |   "What is 3 x 23?" | "Your age?"
==================================================
   "Jason"    |         69          |    26
--------------------------------------------------
  "Subhasish" |        NULL         |    45
```

Comment: here are a bunch of ways http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5Ddynamic+pivot

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Here you go (Please check the column names for typo's):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.qtext) 
            FROM Questions c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT Name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select r.name, a.val,q.qtext from
                registrants r               
                inner join answers a
                on r.id = a.registrant_id
                inner join questions q
                on q.id = a.question_id
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(val)
                for qtext in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 2):

I always liked doing it like this:

```
select
   R.name as Name, 
   A1.val as [What is 3 x 23?],
   A2.val as [Your age?]
from Registrants R
left join Answers A1 on R.id = A1.registrant_id and A1.question_id = 1
left join Answers A2 on R.id = A2.registrant_id and A2.question_id = 2
```